# How to verify the initial text using geb

Tags: spock, geb

I am using geb spoke. For the below html structure I am not able to get the text from specified location:
Below is the html structure:

```
<div class="tab-pane ng-scope active" uib-tab-content-transclude="tab" ng-class="{active: tab.active}" ng-repeat="tab in tabs">
                                                <div id="algemeen-tab-header" class="ng-tab-hdr ng-scope"></div>
                                                <div id="algemeen-tab-body" class="ng-tab-bdy table-view ng-scope">
                                                    <table class="ng-tbl valign-top">
                                                        <tbody class="esuite-table-body">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td class="tp-label">
                                                                    <label class="ng-binding">

                                                                        Reference:

                                                                    </label>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td class="tp-field ng-binding">

                                                                    I-5006-2015

                                                                </td>
                                                                <td class="tp-label ng-hide" ng-show="!zaak.anoniem"></td>
                                                                <td class="tp-field ng-binding ng-hide" ng-show="!zaak.anoniem"></td>
                                                                <td class="tp-label" ng-show="zaak.anoniem"></td>
                                                                <td class="tp-field ng-binding" ng-show="zaak.anoniem"></td>
                                                                <td class="tp-label"></td>
                                                                <td class="tp-field ng-binding"></td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr></tr>
                                                            <tr></tr>
                                                            <tr></tr>
                                                            <tr></tr>
                                                            <tr></tr>
                                                            <tr></tr>
                                                            <tr></tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
```

I wanted to verify the text "I-5006-2015". I am not able to do it. Also, second scenario is that, I just wanted to assert that initial word is "I" from that location. How I can do that.
I have tried below variable to get the location but got failed:

```
  referenceNumberText(wait:true){$("td", class: contains("tp-field ng-binding"))}
```

Please help me on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use html ids rather rarely, the selector for you text would be:

```
$("#algemeen-tab-body > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2)").text()
```

Did you consider naming `<td>`'s? Example:

```
<td id="referenceNumber" class="tp-field ng-binding">
   I-5006-2015
</td>
```

So your selector would be as easy as `$("#referenceNumber").text()`...

Comment: Yes, its working fine for me. Also got the concept. For the second query which I raised I tried with below methods and those are working fine referenceNumberTextValue.text().startsWith("I")